# Unable to assign value in an always-block

Tags: verilog

NO IDEA that the value of register just never changes whatever the clock and the cases are. but no problem while compiling. WHAT is happenning? It is really confusing...

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns

module p2(SW, KEY, LEDR, HEX0, HEX4, HEX5);
  wire t0;
  wire [3:0] A, B, C;
  wire [7:0] AplusB;
  reg [7:0]  register;
  input [3:0] KEY;
  input [9:0] SW;
  output [6:0] HEX0, HEX4, HEX5;
  output [7:0] LEDR;

  assign A = SW[3:0];
  assign B = register[3:0];
  rippleCarryAdder4 a(.X(A), .Y(B), .Cin(1'b0), .Cout(t0), .S(C));
  assign AplusB = {3'b000, t0, C};

  assign LEDR = register;
  HEX h0(.data(A            ), .HEX0(HEX0));
  HEX h4(.data(register[3:0]), .HEX0(HEX4));
  HEX h5(.data(register[7:4]), .HEX0(HEX5));

  always@(posedge KEY[0]) begin
     if (SW[9])
       register[3:0] <= 4'b1111;
     case (KEY[3:1])
       3'b000: register <= AplusB;
       3'b001: register <= {4'b0000, A} + {4'b0000, B};
       3'b010: register <= {A | B, A ^ B};
       3'b011:
         if (A | B)
           register <= 8'b00000001;
       3'b100:
         if ((A & B) == 4'b1111)
           register <= 8'b00000001;
       3'b101: register <= {4'b0000, B} >> A;
       3'b110: register <= {4'b0000, B} << A;
       3'b111: register <= {4'b0000, A} * {4'b0000, B};
       default: ;
  endcase // case (KEY[3:1])
end // always@ (posedge clock)

endmodule // p2

module fullAdder(X, Y, Z, C, S);
  input X, Y, Z;
  output C, S;

  assign C = (X & Y) | ((X ^ Y) & Z);
  assign S = X ^ Y ^ Z;
endmodule // fullAdder

module rippleCarryAdder4(X, Y, Cin, Cout, S);
  input [3:0] X, Y;
  input       Cin;
  output      Cout;
  output [3:0] S;
  wire         c1, c2, c3;

  fullAdder a0(.X(X[0]), .Y(Y[0]), .Z(Cin), .C(c1  ), .S(S[0]));
  fullAdder a1(.X(X[1]), .Y(Y[1]), .Z(c1 ), .C(c2  ), .S(S[1]));
  fullAdder a2(.X(X[2]), .Y(Y[2]), .Z(c2 ), .C(c3  ), .S(S[2]));
  fullAdder a3(.X(X[3]), .Y(Y[3]), .Z(c3 ), .C(Cout), .S(S[3]));
endmodule // rippleCarryAdder4

module HEX(data, HEX0);
  input [3:0] data;
  output [6:0] HEX0;
  wire         c0, c1, c2 , c3;

  assign c0 = data[3];
  assign c1 = data[2];
  assign c2 = data[1];
  assign c3 = data[0];

  assign HEX0[0] = ~c0 & ~c1 & ~c2 &  c3 | ~c0 &  c1 & ~c2 & ~c3 | c0 & ~c1 &  c2 &  c3 |  c0 &  c1 & ~c2 &  c3;
  assign HEX0[1] =  c0 &  c1 &  c2 |  c1 &  c2 & ~c3 |  c0 &  c2 & c3 |  c0 &  c1 & ~c2 & ~c3 | ~c0 &  c1 & ~c2 & c3;
  assign HEX0[2] =  c0 &  c1 &  c2 | ~c0 & ~c1 &  c2 & ~c3 |  c0 & c1 & ~c2 & ~c3;
  assign HEX0[3] = ~c0 & ~c1 & ~c2 &  c3 | ~c0 &  c1 & ~c2 & ~c3 | c1 &  c2 &  c3 |  c0 & ~c1 &  c2 & ~c3;
  assign HEX0[4] = ~c0 &  c3 | ~c0 &  c1 & ~c2 | ~c1 & ~c2 &  c3;
  assign HEX0[5] = ~c0 & ~c1 &  c3 | ~c0 & ~c1 &  c2 | ~c0 &  c2 & c3 |  c0 &  c1 & ~c2 &  c3;
  assign HEX0[6] = ~c0 & ~c1 & ~c2 | ~c0 &  c1 &  c2 &  c3 |  c0 & c1 & ~c2 & ~c3;
endmodule // HEX
```

Comment: Have you looked at the RTL output? Is everything as you expect? What is `SW[9]` doing?

Comment: Be aware that FPGA compilers will happily 'optimize' away entire sections if it thinks there's no useful connections, like Tim suggested, check to see that SW9 is properly assigned to a pin or to logic that hasn't been optimized away (the problem may be with SW9 and not your code)

Comment: Are you sure you mean to use blocking assignment `=` instead of non-blocking assignment `<=` (assuming register is of type `reg` and not type `wire`)? This may affect the compiler's ability to recognize what you're describing. Normally `<=` is used to assign reg variables inside an always@(posedge clock), the compiler recognizes this pattern as sequential logic i.e. a mux followed by a DFF. But if you use blocking assignment, synthesis tool may not recognize it.

Comment: @TomCarpenter SW[9] is well assigned. ALL the problem is just that the value of register does not even change.

Comment: @Tom is it possible for FPGA to ignore all the assignment I did for 'register'? that would be terrible...

Comment: @MarkU I have tried both '=' and '<='. the result turns to be the same that it never changes.

Comment: what is strange is that I named another single reg (the type without [x:y] when defining it), its value does change! but what is the difference? only because it is not an array so that it could change? I am completely confused...

Comment: Well, I can't say for sure, but Quartus once "optimized" a whole DDR3 controller away because it didn't like how I connected the pins, I can't say that's what's happening here though, you'd have to check the RTL to see if SW9 goes to either a set or reset pin or something on 'register'

Comment: The statement that SW[9] is "well assigned" doesn't actually say anything useful - well assigned to what? Can you post the rest of your code.

Comment: @TomCarpenter here it is!

Comment: For a start, the `C` signal in the `p2` module is declared as only 1 bit wide, but you need it to be 4 bits wide. That means in one of the case statements you are assigning don't cares to some of the bits in `register` which may be causing weird optimisations.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I tried it, but nothing changes. thank you though.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I am now wondering if this register is cursed :)

Comment: Well the code looks ok now (the line about `if(SW[9])` doesn't actually do anything, but shouldn't change anything) - it also compiles without warning and doesn't optimise away (I've just compiled and checked the RTL). My only thought is have you got your pin assignments correct in Pin Planner. You need to produce a rising edge on the `KEY[0]` pin in order to make the register change.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yes I did, I use force -r to make KEY[0] behave like a clock sign. but nothing changes ;(

Comment: @TomCarpenter completed get it bro 8) it is my fault that I wrote a force to register in the .do file............sorry for wasting time of all of you Orz